# Finite normal subgroup and subgroup test

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I was tutoring a student today and this problem came up so I need to explain to him using simple ideas but it seems trivial. The question is:
Let $N$ be a finite subgroup of $G$. Show that if $gNg^{-1}\subset N$ then $gNg^{-1} =N$.

I told him that Since the supposition shows that $N$ is a normal subgroup, we automatically get the result by the normal subgroup test (which he said he's proven in class). He asked me what $N$ being finite had to do with anything and I didn't really have an answer for him since this is true for any order... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $N$ is finite, you can show this by counting elements. Since there are $|N|$ distinct elements on both the left and the right, and you have inclusion, you get equality.

Without finiteness, this is *slightly* more annoying to prove. One might prove it by noting that $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ for every $g$ gives also $g^{-1}Ng \subset N$, which rearranges to $N \subset gNg^{-1}$. Clearly, if both sets contain each other, they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the problem is to show that if a finite subgroup contains one of its conjugates, then it is equal to that conjugate. The normal subgroup test tells us that if a subgroup contains all of its conjugates then it is normal and hence equal to all of its conjugates. However, it is possible for a (necessarily infinite) subgroup to properly contain one of its conjugates. Here is an example:

Define a binary operation on the set $G = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z}$ by
$(a,m)(b,n) = (a +2^mb, m+n)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $G$ with this operation is a group.
It is easy to see that $(a,0)^n = (na,0)$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $\langle (a,0) \rangle = \{(na,0) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Let $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (0,1)$. Compute that $yxy^{-1} = (2,0)$. Let $H = \langle x \rangle = \{(n,0)\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then  $yHy^{-1} = \langle yxy^{-1} \rangle = \{(2n,0)\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a proper subgroup of $H$.

In fact if we define $H_n = y^nHy^{-n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then we have $H_{n+1}$ is a proper subgroup of $H_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and all of these subgroups are conjugate.